# Does Outlook graph api cache events?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am making a call to the graph api to get a specific event:

```
                return await graphClient.Me.Events[ExternalID]
                .Request()
                .Expand(singleValueExtendedPropertyExpandString)
                .GetAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The event is properly returned. However, when I try to get the instances for the event:

```
                var instanceException = (await graphClient.Me.Events[ExternalID].Instances
                    .Request(queryOptions)
                    .GetAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false))
                    .Where(i => i.Type == EventType.Exception)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an error from the graph API: "The specified object was not found in the store.".
I used the graph explorer to search for the particular event (with the url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/EXTERNALID) and also received the message that the object could not be found.

I have rerun the code several times and returned the event on the first GET only to receive an error on the second GET.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does the graph api cache GET results?

Answer (score 0):

Does the event appear in the calendar in Outlook or teams' client?
I have faced this issue when creating an event through graph API and sometimes it returns a success response with the event data but the event doesn't appear in either calendars and returns the same error you posted when trying to query it.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear on my Outlook client either